# AngularJS: ui-router: how to get state parameter from child state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

the question sounds a bit stupid. Let me explane what I'm going to achieve.

My simplified code:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('course', {
    url: '/courses/:courseId',
    controller: 'CourseController'
  });
$stateProvider
  .state('course.topic', {
    url: '/topics/:topicId',
    controller: 'TopicController'
  });
```

Without **topicId** it's not possible to show the content, so I would like to know on **course** level if topic is not set - we should set the first topic from the course.

How could I do it with ui-router?

Basically I need to get param from child state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
$stateProvider
  .state('course', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/courses/:courseId',
    controller: 'CourseController'
  })
  .state('course.topic', {
    url: '/topics/:topicId',
    controller: 'TopicController'
  })
  .state('course.firstTopic', {
    url: '',
    controller: 'TopicController'
  });
```

Comment: yes, it could work. But still it looks more like hack for me